# Add another picture to content element in typo3

Tags: typo3

I'm creating my own content element to display some text, some image and another image. This is my tt_content.php file.

```
'logo' => [
     'label' => 'dfasad',
     'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
        'logo',
        [
           'overrideChildTca' => [
              'types' => [
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_TEXT => [
                       'showitem' => '
                          --palette--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                          --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ],
              ],
           ],
        ],
        $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
     ),
 ],
```

This gives me an input field on the backend but it does not get saved on the db.
Probably I need to set that too, right?
I've seen the documentation but is not clear for, I can copy and paste the code and even if would work I would never know why.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a database field in the `ext_tables.sql` file of your extension.

```
CREATE TABLE mytablename (
      logo int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
);
```

You need to set `mytablename` to the name of the table you're extending or your own table name.

See the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/FilesAndLocations/Index.html#ext-tables-sql) for details.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful, there is a table now.

Comment: `mytablename` would be `tt_content` for your custom content element.